# Python Pandas Not Getting Consistent Result using ix

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out why I get a different answer variable type for what seems like the same request.

The data:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'group1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                       'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e'],
                       'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12]})

    group1  group2  value1  value2
0   a   c   1.1     7.1
1   a   c   2.0     8.0
2   a   d   3.0     9.0
3   b   d   4.0     10.0
4   b   d   5.0     11.0
5   b   e   6.0     12.0
```

**Request #1**

```
In [30]:  df.ix[2]
```

Out[30]:

```
group1    a
group2    d
value1    3
value2    9
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

**Request #2**

```
In [35]:    `df.ix[(df['value1']==3)]`

Out[35]:
    group1  group2  value1  value2
2   a   d   3   9
```

Because I get different types of variables for these two operations I can't use the same  procedure to process the results. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: just call `squeeze()` method of the result: `df.ix[2].squeeze()`, `df.ix[(df['value1']==3)].suqeeze()` if you ensure that only one row will be selected.

Comment: The use of squeeze() is valuable to note.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has several ways of doing indexing, depending on what you want. See the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html)

Selecting with a scalar value (like a 2), will drop the dimension of the result (e.g. you will get a Series). To return a frame, pass a list (`[2]` is a single element list)

Select by position (the 3rd element, elements number starting with 0)

```
In [9]: df.iloc[[2]]
Out[9]: 
  group1 group2  value1  value2
2      a      d       3       9

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

Select the row that has the label of 2

```
In [10]: df.ix[[2]]
Out[10]: 
  group1 group2  value1  value2
2      a      d       3       9

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

A boolean indexer that yields True for the row indexed by 2 (note that the parens you used
in the example are superfulous here, `df.ix[(df['value1']==3)]` does exactly the same thing (as do `.ix` and `.loc` in these examples).

```
In [11]: df.loc[df['value1']==3]
Out[11]: 
  group1 group2  value1  value2
2      a      d       3       9

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

Same as above, using the query syntax

```
In [12]: df.query('value1==3')
Out[12]: 
  group1 group2  value1  value2
2      a      d       3       9

[1 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning a motivation for this: if `df.ix[(df['value1']==3)]` automatically squeezed when there was only one True, then you'd have to write code to branch on whether the number of Trues was zero (return a DataFrame?), one (return a Series), or more than one (return a DataFrame again).  Much simpler all around to preserve a distinction between an access method which returns one Series and one which returns a DataFrame, even if the frame has length one.

Comment: what do you mean, its not automatically squeezed. this is a boolean indexer, so it indexes the rows, you get a frame (FYI the parens don't do anything here).

Comment: ?  I'm saying that **if** it automatically squeezed, bad things would happen.

Comment: ahh...ok..you think the OP 'thinks' that it is getting squeezed

Comment: yeah, that's my best guess for why the OP is surprised the two results are the same.

Comment: Thanks you for the help on this.  One item that I found insightful is the double brackets in: df.ix[[2]] and that it denotes one item of a list which forces returning a dataframe.  I really find that helpful.